# 2D convolution along three orthogonals (axis) for 3D volumetric image

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, medical-imaging, 2d-3d-conversion

Since 3D convolution requires too much computational cost, so I prefer to use 2D conv. My motivation here is using 2D conv for volumetric images to reduce this cost.

I want to apply 2D convolution along three orthogonals to get 3 results, each belongs to one of these orthogonals. More clearly, suppose I have a 3D volumetric image. Instead of apply 3D conv, I want to use 2D conv both xy, xz, yz axis. Then, I expect that 3 different volumetric results. Each result represent three different orthogonals.

Is there way to do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can permute your images. (Some frameworks such as `numpy` calls it `transpose`).

Assume we use `3 x 3` a convolutional kernel.

```
# A batch of 16 3 channel images (channels first)
a = tensor(shape=[16,3,1920,1080])

# 2D conv will slide over a `1920 x 1080` image, kernel size is `3 x 3 x 3`
a.shape is (16,3,1920,1080)

# 2D conv will slide over a `3 x 1080` image, kernel size is `1920 x 3 x 3`
a.permute(0,2,1,3)
a.shape is (16,1920,3,1080)

# 2D conv will slide over a `1920 x 3` image, kernel size is `1080 x 3 x 3`
a.permute(0,3,2,1)
a.shape is (16,1080,1920,3)
```

Comment: What if I have tensor with 5 element initially (batch, channel, depth, height, width)? 
Let' say my initial tensor shape is : [1,1,5,192,192], then what should be the input of my 2d conv parameters? I will use the PyTorch framework

torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size,...)

Comment: The general idea is the same, you just have to accommodate for another dimension, and permute four times. However, it is stated in PyTorch's documentation that `Conv2d` inputs tensors of shape `(N,C,H,W)`, so I don't think it can handle your extra dimension natively.

Comment: your initial response is no nice, thank you. But I have a confusion about shapes. 1) your initial height-width is 32x32. Then  how it becomes 1080 and 1920. What causese this?

Comment: Oh! that's a mistake, my bad. I initially tried with `32 x 32` but changed it to `1920 x 1080` midway to have differently sized axes. It is supposed to start with `a = tensor(shape=[16,3,1920,1080])`. I will edit my post!

Comment: Okey then, I will try and inform you with my  results. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and applied in my network. However, I think, heigh and width (like 1080,1920)  may be too large for kernel size. Is there any problem if I use (3x3x3) for each orthogonal? thank you

Comment: I just used `1920 x 1080` resolution images as an example, you can use whatever you want. The kernel features need to match the image features though. E.g. If you want to convolve over a `123 x 32 x 16` image, the convolution kernel must also have `123` features. In the case of a `3 x 3` kernel, the kernel shape would be `123 x 3 x 3`.